# Using CSS to align a button bottom of the screen using relative positions

Tags: html, css

I need to position a button to the bottom of the screen. I need to use relative size and not absolute sizes, so it fits any screen size.

my CSS code:

```
position:relative;
left:20%;
right:20%;
bottom:5%;
top:60%;
```

Comment: please share your html code, also http://jsfiddle.net/ is better.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you're not using JavaScript, I think you're better off first creating two divs. Each with a set proportion and the lower one should contain your button. Perhaps more code from your end should let the others know what you've already done.

Comment: This couldn't be done you have to use position:absolute for this....

Comment: `position: fixed; z-index; 1000`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The below css code always keep the button at the bottom of the page

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
```

Since you want to do it in **relative positioning**, you should go for `margin-top:100%`

```
position:relative;
margin-top:100%;
```

**EDIT1:** [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/y4PZ6/1/)

**EDIT2:** To place button at center of the screen,

```
position:relative;
left: 50%;
margin-top:50%;
```

[JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/y4PZ6/2/)

Comment: I don't want it exactly on the bottom, but i need to keep a space between bottom of the screen and the button.

Comment: @sharonHwk check the jsfiddle in my answer, you may get some idea.

Comment: How could i get the button to the center of the screen?

Comment: @sharonHwk check JSFiddle2 in my answer. I think, this is what you're expecting.

Comment: At times when i change the screen size, the button is not centered

Comment: @sharonHwk If possible post your HTML code, so that we can see the height and width of the outer element.

Comment: @sharonHwk I'm not sure whether this is what you're trying.  Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/y4PZ6/3/)

Answer (score 7):

This will work for any resolution,

```
button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    right:20%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BUuSr/

Comment: I also want it to be center

Comment: I tried your code and if the width of the screen gets bigger, then the button is still positioned at 20%, so is there anyway i could center the button ?

Comment: `left: 50%;` or `right: 50%;` will center it

Comment: `width`, `left` and `right` must be 100%, that way you can center the button

Answer (score 3):

```
<button style="position: absolute; left: 20%; right: 20%; bottom: 5%;"> Button </button>
```